# PHP error with variable in callback function

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I have this function in php (laravel):

```
    public static function isUserParticipatesInTournament($tourId, $userId)
    {
        var_dump($userId); //dumped
        $user = User::find($userId);

        if(!$user)
        {
            return null;
        }

        $obj = $user->whereHas('tournaments', function($query)
        {
            var_dump($tourId); //error
            $query->where('id', '=', $tourId); //error
        })->get();

        return $obj;
    }
```

The problem is that in the closure `$obj = $user->whereHas('tournaments', function($query){...}` the `$tourId` variable is undefined in it. I am getting this error:
`Undefined variable: userId`.

Why this is happening? The variable is declared in the scope of the inner function. My only thought is that, that it is a callback function.

When I tried to execute this function : `$obj = $user->whereHas('tournaments', function($query, $tourId){...}` then I am getting this exception:

```
Missing argument 2 for User::{closure}()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `$tourId` variable is not in the scope of your anonymous function.  Have a look at the `use` keyword to see how you can add it to the scope.  See example 3 on this page: http://www.php.net//manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

It should look something like the following:

```
$obj = $user->whereHas('tournaments', function($query) use($tourId)
    {
        var_dump($tourId); // Dumps OK
    })->get();
```